# FFMpeg library: how to precisely seek in an audio file

Tags: android, c++, ffmpeg

Using the FFMpeg library in my Android app, I try to understand how I can seek in an audio file, at a very precise position.

For example, I want to set the current position in my file to the frame #1234567 (in a file encoded at 44100 Hz), which is equivalent to seek at 27994.717 milliseconds.

To achieve that, here is what I tried:

```
// this:
av_seek_frame(formatContext, -1, 27994717, 0);

// or this:
av_seek_frame(formatContext, -1, 27994717, AVSEEK_FLAG_ANY);

// or even this:
avformat_seek_file(formatContext, -1, 27994617, 27994717, 27994817, 0);
```

Using a position in microseconds gives me the best result so far.

But for some reason, the positioning is not totally accurate: when I extract the samples from the audio file, it doesn't start exactly at the expected position. There is a slight delay of about 30-40 milliseconds (even if I seek to the position 0, surprisingly...).

Do I use the function the right way, or even the right function?

**EDIT**

Here is how I can get the position:

```
AVPacket packet;
AVStream *stream = NULL;
AVFormatContext *formatContext = NULL;
AVCodec *dec = NULL;

// initialization:
avformat_open_input(&formatContext, filename, NULL, NULL);
avformat_find_stream_info(formatContext, NULL);
int audio_stream_index = av_find_best_stream(formatContext, AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO, -1, -1, &dec, 0);
stream = formatContext->streams[audio_stream_index];

...

// later, when I extract samples, here is how I get my position, in microseconds:
av_read_frame(formatContext, &packet);
long position = (long) (1000000 * (packet.pts * ((float) stream->time_base.num / stream->time_base.den)));
```

Thanks to that piece of code, I can get the position of the beginning of the current frame (frame = bloc of samples, the size depends on the audio format - 1152 samples for mp3, 128 to 1152 for ogg, ...)

**The problem is:** the value I get in `position` is not accurate: it's actually 30 ms late, approximately. For example, when it says 1000000, the actual position is approximately 1030000...

What did I do wrong? Is it a bug in FFMpeg?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm currious to know what your *actual* application of this is where a 40ms delay/offset actually matters? For most desktop applications or games a 40ms delay would most likely be insignificant. What are you doing where this actually matters? Even on a video, a 40ms deleay in the audio is unlikely to be noticeable.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Because I'm working on some kind of a DJ app, so the position in each song I'm mixing have to be as precise as possible (so I try to have a delay below 1ms)

Comment: Thank's for the explanation. That makes sense.

Comment: I want to add that MPlayer, that likely uses the same libraries, also has that positioning glitch. It always reports position when it plays mp3, and positioning onto that position is more or less accurate, unless you use the "seek +-N sec" controls, after which the reported position becomes wrong, sometimes by a minute in a 5-minute recording. A human workaround to that MPlayer problem is to play at 2x-4x speed instead of using the "seek forward" functionality.

Answer (score 5):

Late, but hopefully, it helps someone. The idea is to save timestamp when seeking and then compare *AVPacket->pts* with this value (You can do that with  *AVStream->dts*, but it wasn't giving good results in my experiments). If *pts* is still lower than our target timestamp, then skip frames using *AV_PKT_DATA_SKIP_SAMPLES* ability of *AVPacket->side_data*.

Code for seeking method:

```
void audio_decoder::seek(float seconds) {
    auto stream = m_format_ctx->streams[m_packet->stream_index];

    // convert seconds provided by the user to a timestamp in a correct base,
    // then save it for later.
    m_target_ts = av_rescale_q(seconds * AV_TIME_BASE, AV_TIME_BASE_Q, stream->time_base);

    avcodec_flush_buffers(m_codec_ctx.get());

    // Here we seek within given stream index and the correct timestamp 
    // for that stream. Using AVSEEK_FLAG_BACKWARD to make sure we're 
    // always *before* requested timestamp.
    if(int err = av_seek_frame(m_format_ctx.get(), m_packet->stream_index, m_target_ts, AVSEEK_FLAG_BACKWARD)) {
        error("audio_decoder: Error while seeking ({})", av_err_str(err));
    }
}
```

And code for decoding method:

```
void audio_decoder::decode() {
   <...>

   while(is_decoding) {
       // Read data as usual.
       av_read_frame(m_format_ctx.get(), m_packet.get());

       // Here is the juicy part. We were seeking, but the seek 
       // wasn't precise enough so we need to drop some frames.
       if(m_packet->pts > 0 && m_target_ts > 0 && m_packet->pts < m_target_ts) {
            auto stream = m_format_ctx->streams[m_packet->stream_index];

            // Conversion from delta timestamp to frames.
            auto time_delta = static_cast<float>(m_target_ts - m_packet->pts) / stream->time_base.den;
            int64_t skip_frames = time_delta * m_codec_ctx->time_base.den / m_codec_ctx->time_base.num;

            // Next step: we need to provide side data to our packet,
            // and it will tell the codec to drop frames.
            uint8_t *data = av_packet_get_side_data(m_packet.get(), AV_PKT_DATA_SKIP_SAMPLES, nullptr);
            if(!data) {
                 data = av_packet_new_side_data(m_packet.get(), AV_PKT_DATA_SKIP_SAMPLES, 10);
            }

            // Define parameters of side data. You can check them here:
            // https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavc__packet.html#ga9a80bfcacc586b483a973272800edb97
            *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(data) = skip_frames;
            data[8] = 0;
        }

        // Send packet as usual.
        avcodec_send_packet(m_codec_ctx.get(), m_packet.get());

        // Proceed to the receiving frames as usual, nothing to change there.
   }
   <...>
}
```

If it's unclear without context, you can check the same code in my project [audio_decoder.cpp](https://github.com/barsoosayque/libgdx-oboe/blob/master/library/src/cpp/mediacodec/audio_decoder.cpp).

Comment: Thanks, worth a try. I'll try that later on.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the codec. For example aac has a resolution of 1024 samples per frame, no matter what the sample rate, it also has priming samples that may be discarded. MP3 has 576 or 1152 samples per frame depending on the layer.

If you need perfection, use an uncompressed format like wav or riff.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm sure there is a way: other libraries are capable of doing what I want to achieve, even with mp3. And it seems like FFMpeg can do that too, but for some reason, it's not totally accurate. So, as I'm thinking of a workaround, is there then possible to get the actual current position?

Comment: There is a way, you need to add a second step. After ffmpeg decodes to an approximate position, you need to throw away the samples you don’t need to achieve sub frame seeking.

Answer (score 0):

Combining small pieces of information from the internet about this topic,
I've managed to seek precisely using this technique (tested in an android app only).

```
// --> Setup
AVFormatContext* formatContext;
AVCodecContext* codecContext;

// ...

int sample_rate = 44100;
int channel_count = 2;

// --> Do seek
bool seek_pending = true;
double seek_target_s = 4.5;

// ...

// --> Decode
bool is_eof = false;
int result = -1;

AVPacket* audioPacket = av_packet_alloc();
AVFrame* audioFrame = av_frame_alloc();

while (!is_eof) {
  if (seek_pending) {
    int64_t seek_ts = seek_target_s * AV_TIME_BASE - 0.05 * AV_TIME_BASE;
    if (seek_ts < 0) seek_ts = 0;
    avformat_seek_file(formatContext, -1, 0, seek_ts, INT64_MAX, 0);
    avcodec_flush_buffers(codecContext);
  }
  
  av_read_frame(formatContext, audioPacket);
  avcodec_send_packet(codecContext, audioPacket);
  av_packet_unref(audioPacket);

  while (result >= 0) {
    result = avcodec_receive_frame(codecContext, audioFrame);
    if (result < 0) continue;
    
    AVRational audio_time_base = (AVRational){1, sample_rate * channel_count};
    audioFrame->pts = av_rescale_q(audioFrame->pts, codecContext->pkt_timebase, audio_time_base);
    audio_pts = audioFrame->pts - delayedSamples * channel_count;
    
    int skip_samples = 0;
    
    if (seek_pending) {
      int64_t seek_pts = seek_target_s * channel_count * sample_rate;
      int64_t next_pts = audio_pts + audioFrame->nb_samples * channel_count;
      
      if (next_pts < seek_pts) {
        av_frame_unref(audioFrame);
        continue;
      }
      else {
        skip_samples = seek_pts - audio_pts;
      }
    }
    
    seek_pending = false;
    
    int samples_count = audioFrame->nb_samples * channel_count;
    process_frame(audioFrame->data, samples_count, skip_samples);

    av_frame_unref(audioFrame);
  }
}
```

It was tested on mp3 files. I omit error checking and resampling for simplicity.

*Code details:*

- `seek_target_s` is in seconds, just to avoid dividing it by 1000.0
- I convert `audioFrame->pts` to samples, as well as other PTS related values, `audio_pts`, `seek_pts`, `next_pts`
  (`audioFrame->nb_samples` is the total number of audio samples in a frame divided by number of channels,
  so I multiply some values by `channel_count` but it's just simpler for me to read the code)

The main idea is to seek to 50ms before the target time and then search to the exact frame and sample that matches the target time.
The `if (next_pts < seek_pts)` part skips frames that don't "contain" the target time.
When the correct frame is found, the `else` part checks how many samples away the target time is from the frame start.

Then `process_frame` is a custom method that does something with the audio data (write to a stream or a file for example).
`samples_count` is the total number of audio samples to process (each sample is a float or signed 16-bit PCM value depending on the format).
`skip_samples` is how many samples to omit from those `samples_count` from the data beginning (will be processed the last `samples_count - skip_samples` values).

*Some details on my investigation:*

I needed an audio loop with exact time bounds in milliseconds.
When passing `0` as seek flags, I heard a small chunk of silence at the beginning of the loop, maybe a couple of ms.
Though by listening to the loop I'd say the seek was exact, it just lost some initial audio data.
So I've printed the frame data to the log just after the seek and saw it had `0x00` bytes in ~1.5 initial frames.

Then I tried to seek using `av_seek_frame` and `AVSEEK_FLAG_BACKWARD` flag.
It was a bit better as the silence at the loop beginning was shorter, but it was still there.

So my final "dirty" solution was to go a bit further then with the `AVSEEK_FLAG_BACKWARD` flag and rewind to an arbitrary constant and small amount of time (50ms was enough for me).